# regexp, how to match longer strings first?

Tags: regex, matlab

There must be an option/flag for this I missed with matlab:

I want to use regular expressions to match to my given string, but multiple matches are possible. I want them sorted to first match the longer ones, before the shorter ones.

How can this be achieved?

```
regexpi('A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.','quick|the|a','match','once')
%returns 'A', would like it to return 'quick'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following code

```
% match all possible key words, don't use argument 'once' in `regexpi()`
v = regexpi('A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.','quick|the|a','match');
% calculate the lengths of matched words
lens = cellfun(@length,v);
% output the longest word
v{lens == max(lens)}
```

such that

```
ans = quick
```

Comment: is there no regex possibility for this?

Comment: @user2305193 I am not sure if there are other ways to make it, frankly speaking...

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
>> regexpi('A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.','.*?(quick)|.*?(the)|.*?(a)','tokens','once')

ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {'quick'}
```

but that's pretty ugly. Another solution, which is a smidge less ugly, is

```
>> str = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
>> list = ["quick" "the" "a"];

>> list(find(arrayfun(@(x)contains(str,x), list), 1))

ans = 

    "quick"
```

I think I like Thomas' solution the most.